# Quadrature domains for arc length

Tags: cv.complex-variables, sp.spectral-theory

Is ellipse a quadrature domain for arc-length measure? 
More precisely does there exist points $z_1,\cdots,z_n$ inside an ellipse $E$ and non zero constants $c_1,\cdots,c_n$ such that $$\int _Ep(z)\,ds_z=\sum_1^nc_kp(z_k)$$
holds for all polynomials $p$?

**Motivation:**
In the literature, there are various results regarding characterization of domains in $\mathbb R^N$ via eigenvalues of integral (in particular potential) operators. A prime example is the following theorem of E. Fraenkel:

> **Theorem.**(Fraenkel 2000)
>   Let $G⊂\mathbb R^N$
>   be a bounded open set and let $ω_N$ be the surface measure of the unit-sphere in $\mathbb R^N$. Consider
>   $$u(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_G\log|x-y|dy, &  n=2 \\ \frac{1}{N-2}\int_G\frac{1}{\|x-y\|^N-2}dy, &  n\geq 3 \end{cases}.$$
>   If $u$ is constant on $∂G$ then $G$ is a ball.

One can ask similar question for the case that the operator on hand is defined by integration over boundary of closed curves against a singular kernel function, e.g. single layer potentials. Existence of quadrature formulas drastically simplifies the situation for such operators.

Comment: It might help MOers who want to think about this problem to know that there is significant literature about quadrature domains for arc-length, which I had never heard of before today.  I'd recommend that anyone who wants to think about this problem do some reading to find out what is known.  (E.g., start by doing a web search for papers on quadrature domains, which often mention literature on quadrature domains for arc-length.)

Answer (score 1):

No, the ellipse is not a quadrature domain for arclength.  Using (see chapter 7 of Davis's book listed below) $dz = \frac{dz}{ds} ds$ and $\frac{dz}{ds} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{S'(z)}}$, where $S(z)$ denotes the Schwarz function of the ellipse (defined to be complex analytic and satisfying $S(z)=\bar{z}$ on the ellipse), we have $$\int_{E}g(z)ds = \int_{E} g(z) \sqrt{S'(z)} dz.$$
Then using, e.g., a modification of the proof of the second theorem in Chapter 14 of Davis's book listed below, if $E$ were a quadrature domain for arclength, then $\sqrt{S'(z)}$ would extend as a meromorphic function in the interior of the ellipse.  But this is not the case as $S(z)$, and consequently $\sqrt{S'(z)}$ as well, has a branch cut singularity on the segment joining the foci of the ellipse.

*Davis, Philip J.*, The Schwarz function and its applications, The Carus Mathematical Monographs. No. 17. Washington, D.C.: The Mathematical Association of America. XI, 228 p. (1974). [ZBL0293.30001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0293.30001).